# try to return all rows in a table and count the amount of rows with matching ID from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables. Table one is `products_cat_arabic` and table two is `products_arabic`.

I need to get the names of each `cat` from `products_cat_arabic` with the numbers of the related `cat_id` from the other table.
This is my query:

```
<?php
    $getCats = $db->query(
    'SELECT c.*, COUNT(*) as num_items 
    FROM products_cat_arabic c 
    JOIN products_arabic q ON q.id = c.id 
    GROUP BY c.id'
    );
while ($gCat = mysqli_fetch_array($getCats)) {
?>
<li class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><a href="#"><?php print $gCat['cat_name']; ?>
    </a><span
        title="products number"><?php print $gCat['num_items']; ?></span></li>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Got the names of each cat but the number of the products is wrong.

Edit:

```
SELECT c.cat_name, COUNT(*) as num_items 
FROM products_cat_arabic c 
JOIN products_arabic q ON q.cat = c.id 
GROUP BY c.id
```

Got the count right but I have 3 category can see 2 only as the last one don't have any products in.

Comment: `SELECT cat_name,COUNT(*)  as....GROUP BY cat_name` I suspect that selecting * and GROUP BY id is wrong

Comment: what error did you see?

Comment: I don't get Error I get the wrong count

Comment: @Mihai I tried  `SELECT cat_name` same results

Comment: Edit your question with some sample data from both tables

Comment: I updated my query see my edit

Comment: Use my query above but instead of JOIN use LEFT JOIN (or RIGHT JOIN depending on your data)

Comment: Did but now I got the third category with count of one, it should be 0

Comment: Use COUNT(col name) since COUNT(*) also count the NULLs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT c.cat_name,
      t.nb as num_items 
FROM products_cat_arabic c
INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT COUNT(*) as nb, products_arabic.cat
   FROM products_arabic
   GROUP BY products_arabic.cat) t ON t.cat = c.id
GROUP BY c.cat_name
```

Comment: @Jean Doux always add some text explaining your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.cat_name, COUNT(q.cat) as num_items FROM products_arabic q 
LEFT JOIN products_cat_arabic c ON q.cat = c.id 
GROUP BY q.cat
```

I'm not sure, but I guess `q.cat` is related to `c.cat_name` and not to `c.id`. Anyway, I dunno really about your table but you can change the join `q.cat = c.id` if it's wrong.